# How to create custom PHP/Mysql page in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: php

I'm currently assigned to create custom page in ExpressionEngine (because that's the old code). I'm not getting used to ExpressionEngine and CodeIgniter either. I do inspecting the structure of current code then I decide to put my script to the template so I just choose the template when I create new page in ExpressionEngine admin page.

The question is: How to put my custom PHP script to that template because I could not find one PHP script in other template before? or If my way is wrong, How to create custom PHP page in ExpressionEngine?

FYI: custom script is want to connect to other server DB and google map API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each template has it's own set of preferences. Go to your list of templates in the control panel.  For the template where you wish to enable PHP click on "Edit Preferences" and under "Allow PHP" select "Yes".

You can then choose to have PHP parsed before or after EE tags, depending on whether you are passing data from PHP to EE or vice versa.

Note that enabling PHP has security implications and adds a little overhead to the processing of the page.

Comment: Your up vote is all the thanks I need.  :-)